# d3.json response inside wrong callback variable

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a little application in PHP for a website.
For this application i use neo4j community database.

I'm trying to create nice looking navigation with a graph. The problem is not the styling but to get the graph running.

Right now i get the output of neoclient (the php solution to communicate with neo4j database) and creating JSON (ON MY OWN! I need this step because, i want to add data of other scripts later... sry : ( ).

Now i want to use this data and create a graph of it. All i'm getting is that all nodes and links are given as error. Funny thing is that i can say graph = error in javascript and the points (NOT THE LINKS : () get printed.

I really searched through many things and tried with examples but I can't find the answer of what I'm doing wrong. Hope this question is not to stupid and didn't get asked to frequently. I admit I'm new to d3j. Can somebody say what is wrong?

complete json: http://meggeslp.noxxkn.de/graph.json

generated by:

```
<?php namespace engine\encoder;
class GraphJSONEncoder {

    public static function encodeNeo4JResponse($response) {
        $result = "{ ";
        //$result .= '"comment": "Automatic Generated JSON Response by HIDDEN ; )" , ';
        $result .= '"nodes": [ ';
        $i = 0;
        $num = count($response->getNodes());
        $ids = [];
        foreach ($response->getNodes() as $node) {
            $result .= "{ ";
            foreach($node->getProperties() as $name => $prop) {
                $result .= '"'.$name.'": "'.$prop.'", ';
            }
            $result .= '"label": "'.$node->getLabel().'",';
            $result .= '"id": '. $node->getId().' ';
            $result .= " }";
            if(++$i !== $num) {
                $result .= ", ";
            } 

            $id[$node->getId()] = $i-1;
        }

        $result.= '], "links": [ ';
        $i = 0;
        $num = count($response->getRelationships());
        foreach ($response->getRelationships() as $rel) {
            $result .= "{";

            $result .= '"source": '.$id[$rel->getStartNode()->getId()].',';
            $result .= '"target": '.$id[$rel->getEndNode()->getId()].',';
            $result .= '"type": "'.$rel->getType().'",';
            $result .= '"weight": 1';
            $result .= " }";

            if(++$i !== $num) {
                $result .= ", ";
            } 
        }

        $result.= "]}";

        return $result;
    }
}
```

The Function get used like this: (graphgenerator.php)

```
<?php namespace mygn;

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php'; 

use mygn\application\Application;
use engine\database\Query;
use engine\encoder\GraphJSONEncoder;

$app = Application::getInstance();
$app->init();
$app->run();
$result = $app->dbProxy()->query(new Query("neo4j", "MATCH n-[r]->g RETURN n,r,g;"));
?><?= GraphJSONEncoder::encodeNeo4JResponse($result) ?>
```

And finally (sry for the stuff above, if it wasn't needed) to the actual problem:

```
<?php namespace mygn;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

use mygn\application\Application;
use engine\database\Query;

$app = Application::getInstance();
$app->init();
$app->run();

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
    <head >
    <title>MYGN</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="external/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="external/jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="external/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.3"  charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body style="height:100%">
    <div id="graph" style="height:100%"></div>
    <script>
        var width = 800, height = 800;
        // force layout setup
        var force = d3.layout.force()
                .charge(-200).linkDistance(30).size([width, height]);

        // setup svg div
        var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%")
                .attr("pointer-events", "all");

        // load graph (nodes,links) json from /graph endpoint
        d3.json("calls/graphgenerator.php", function(error, graph) {
            console.log(error);
            graph = error;
            force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .links(graph.links)
                .start();

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link");

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .call(force.drag);

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

            force.on("tick", function() {
                link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
          });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

you see know in line 41 "graph = error" ... i really don't understand why all is just simply "error" and it is quite frustrating. If i do this step with "graph = error" all nodes get painted but the links not.

I tried to do something like mentioned here: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/
I had to add the "weight:" property to print the graph. (mentioned in other stackoverflow questions). Also i want to add if you look at the encoder i already know that i have to use the ids of the arrays for the links and not the original ids ... but maybe i still do this wrong ? Can somebody help pls?

Hope this question is ok to ask.

Greets Noxxer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `graph` being undefined is, that you are using a very old version (from 2012) of d3.js. I tested your code with a newer version and it works just fine. So you should include it like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And your Links are being generated, but not visible. You have to add a strokecolor to your links like so:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
  .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Or you set the `stroke` via CSS with this in your html head:

```
<style>
  .link { stroke: black; }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you so much ... and i'm just sitting here like "._____________:" .. omg i'm so sry and thank you